# How to get an ascii value of a NSString*, pointing to a character?

Tags: objective-c

When presented with an `@"a"`, i'd like to be able to get it's ascii value of 97.

I thought this does it

```
NSString *c = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"a"];
NSLog(@"%d", [c intValue]); // Prints 0, expected 97
```

But ... you guessed it (or knew it :)) .. it does not.

**How can i get an ascii value of a NSString*, pointing to a single character?**

Comment: Note that "ascii" is a bit of a misnomer here, because NSString can hold unicode characters. Don't assume that the result of `[str characterAtIndex:0]` will be in the range 0-255.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%d",[c characterAtIndex:0]);
```

[NSString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html): The integer value of the receiver’s text, assuming a decimal representation and skipping whitespace at the beginning of the string. Returns INT_MAX or INT_MIN on overflow. **Returns 0 if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid decimal text representation of a number**.

So it returned 0 because you called intValue on invalid decimal text representation of a number.

Answer (score 6):

```
NSString *str = @"a";
unichar chr = [str characterAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"ascii value %d", chr);
```

And why your method does not work is because you are operating on a STRING remember? Not a single character. Its still a NSString.