# How to remove ' from NSString in sqlite query

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

Trying to remove ' from this sentence 'hey i’ll come tomorrow'. Tried`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` also but it doesn't work. Please help in finding solution to this as i have wasted my more than a half day on this already. Below is the query and what i tried plus the output, please check

```
 NSMutableString *msql = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"insert into %@ ", tableName];
        for (int i=0; i<[arrArguments count]; i++){
            NSMutableArray *marrArgum = [arrArguments objectAtIndex:i];

            if (i==0){
[msql appendFormat:@"SELECT '%@' AS 'id', '%@' AS 'UserID', '%@' AS 'MessageID', '%@' AS 'ActualMessage', '\%@\' AS 'MessageType', '%@' AS 'MessageIsOld', '%@' AS 'MessageSentBySelf', '%@' AS 'Timestamp', '%@' AS 'MessageRead', '%@' AS 'MessageToUser' ", [marrArgum objectAtIndex:0], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:1], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:2], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:3], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:4], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:5], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:6], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:7], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:8], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:9]];

}
            else{
                [msql appendFormat:@"UNION ALL SELECT '%@', '%@', '%@', '\%@\', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@' ", [marrArgum objectAtIndex:0], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:1], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:2], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:3], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:4], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:5], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:6], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:7], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:8], [marrArgum objectAtIndex:9]];
            }

NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", msql];
DBLog(@"INSERT SQL QUERY: %@", sql);
        METHOD_CALLER;
        int intQcheck = sqlite3_exec(sqliteDB, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err);
        DBLog(@"intQcheck = %d", intQcheck);
        if (intQcheck!= SQLITE_OK) {
            if ([self targetAppIsUsingDevProfile])
                NSAssert(0, @"Error in Insertion Query(intQcheck=%d): %@", intQcheck, strMsql);
            success = NO;
        }
```

What i tried is:

```
NSString *strMsql = [sql stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\'"];
```

But it doesn't work. Output is still same as earlier which is:

```
i’ll see u you
```

Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: what about replacing with an empty string rather that \'?

Comment: same output no change

Comment: `'` != `’`. One is "straight", the other one is "curved". That's not the same character.

Comment: done that way also, copied the same and pasted in code also while replacing but doesn't work no effect

Comment: I'd suggest you to find the character code with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508283/how-to-get-an-ascii-value-of-a-nsstring-pointing-to-a-character (you might use a for loop printing the item as a NSString and as a ASCII Value and check which is it).

Comment: This is why you bind values to parameters in a statement instead of trying to insert them directly in a string.

Comment: What does the SQL statement have to do with the character replacement? The 2 things seem completely unrelated to me.

Comment: My requirements are little different so i think i need to paste some more code in question for clear understanding. Please check my question again

Answer (score 1):

**Why Prepared Statements Should Be Favoured**

When you create SQL queries yourself as a string, they almost always contain parts of a user's input. An attacker can take advantage of this by, for example, cleverly changing the semantics of the query using `'` and thus gaining unauthorized access to data or destroying data.

This is called SQL injection and is one of the top most critical security risks, see here:
https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf

**Defense**

> The use of prepared statements with variable binding (aka parameterized queries) is how all developers should first be taught how to write database queries.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28with_Parameterized_Queries.29

**How to use prepared statements with SQLite and iOS**

For prepared statements see https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html.

Basic steps are:

- create the prepared statement
- bind values to parameters
- run the SQL
- destroy the object to avoid resource leaks

Here is a simple example:

```
-(BOOL)insertValue:(NSString *)value intoDB:(sqlite3 *)db {
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
    NSString *insertStmt = @"insert into SomeTable (sometext) values (?)";
    //create the prepared statement
    if(SQLITE_OK == sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertStmt.UTF8String, -1, &stmt, NULL)) {
        //bind values to parameters
        if(SQLITE_OK == sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, value.UTF8String, -1, SQLITE_STATIC)) {
            //run the SQL
            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(stmt)) {
                return NO;
            }
        }
        else {
            return NO;
        }
        //destroy the object to avoid resource leaks
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

It would be called for your example string `i'll see u you` like this:

```
sqlite3 *db;
if(SQLITE_OK == sqlite3_open(dbURL.absoluteString.UTF8String, &db)) {
    NSString *someValue = @"i'll see u you";
    if (![self insertValue:someValue intoDB:db]) {
        NSLog(@"insert failed: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"open db failed: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
```

So here the use of `'` e.g. from a user input can't do any harm, because we use a prepared statement.

**Demo**

If you look at the data in a database utility, it looks like this after this insert statement:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your "BTW" at the end of the answer should be the actual answer. No one should be building SQL queries using string formats. Only use prepared statements. Let the underlying SQLite API do the proper quoting and escaping as needed. This is the primary cause of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @rmaddy You are right, I should not only mention it briefly at the end of the answer in one sentence, but it is extremely important to point it out explicitly. I have created a small example and rewritten my answer accordingly.

Comment: @StephanSchlecht My requirements are little different so i think i need to paste some more code in question for clear understanding. Please check my question again

Comment: As mentioned by several commentators, for security reasons it is not recommended to assemble SQL as strings. Take another look at my example and read the referenced texts. That takes care of proper quoting and escaping. That being said, if you want to escape `'` so that it appears as `\'` in the output, you have to use `\\'` in your replacement, so you need to use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"]`